# Downgrading the `kernel-devel-3.10.0-xxx.el7.x86_64.rpm`

Tags: centos, software-installation, yum, rpm

I use the wget download the `kernel-devel`, then I want install it, but it seems has been installed by `yum`:

```
$ rpm -i kernel-devel-3.10.0-327.el7.x86_64.rpm
warning: kernel-devel-3.10.0-327.el7.x86_64.rpm: Header V4 DSA/SHA1 Signature, key ID 192a7d7d: NOKEY
error: can't create transaction lock on /var/lib/rpm/.rpm.lock (Permission denied)
[echou@localhost kernel]$ sudo rpm -i kernel-devel-3.10.0-327.el7.x86_64.rpm
[sudo] password for echou: 
warning: kernel-devel-3.10.0-327.el7.x86_64.rpm: Header V4 DSA/SHA1 Signature, key ID 192a7d7d: NOKEY
    package kernel-devel-3.10.0-693.11.6.el7.x86_64 (which is newer than kernel-devel-3.10.0-327.el7.x86_64) is already installed
```

So, how to downgrade it?

---

**EDIT**

I tried use `kernel-devel-uname-r == $(uname -r)` to special the version:

```
$ sudo yum install "kernel-devel-uname-r == $(uname -r)"
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: ftp.cuhk.edu.hk
 * epel: ftp.cuhk.edu.hk
 * extras: ftp.cuhk.edu.hk
 * updates: ftp.cuhk.edu.hk
No package kernel-devel-uname-r == 3.10.0-327.el7.x86_64 available.
Error: Nothing to do
```

But also failed.

Answer (score 1):

```
sudo yum downgrade ./kernel-devel-3.10.0-327.el7.x86_64.rpm
```

Tested on CentOS 7.4

Answer (score 0):

Just use yum remove the newer `kernel-devel`:

```
yum remove kernel-devel-3.10.0-327.el7.x86_64.rpm
```

Then you can use `rpm` to install it:

```
rpm -i kernel-devel-3.10.0-327.el7.x86_64.rpm
```